# adding generic image if empty or broken

Tags: php, file-exists

i have a products portfolio each one has an image, if the DB field 'image' is empty i'm loading a generic image, but if in some case the field has an image value but the file doesn't exists i want to use the generic image too, i've tried using the code below but only works for empty fields:

```
<div class="wrapper"><a href="store.php?url=<?php echo $row->url ?>"><img src="images/stores/category/

<?php           
if (empty($row->image) or file_exists($row->image)==false) { 
    echo 'generic.jpg';
}else{                  
    echo $row->imagen; }?>" alt="<?php echo $row->seo ?>"/></a></div>        
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is this a typo `$row->imagen`?

Comment: Use `is_file` instead of `file_exists`. This last one will also return true if the path is a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good code should be like this:

Note 1: use is_file to check of the file actually exists and is available

Note 2: use the relative path from your script to the file since the field contains *only* the file name

Note 3: typo on the $row->imagen

```
<div class="wrapper"><a href="store.php?url=<?php echo $row->url ?>"><img src="images/stores/category/

<?php           
if (empty($row->image) || !is_file('images/stores/category/' . $row->image)) { 
    echo 'generic.jpg';
}else{                  
    echo $row->image; }?>" alt="<?php echo $row->seo ?>"/></a></div>        
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: the typo was a translation mistake, that's the real field name, the DB is in spanish. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

file_exists should point to something in the file system.

Try something like this:

```
if (file_exists('/Library/WebServer/Documents/theimage.jpg')) {
  echo 'File exists';
} else {
  echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

OR

```
if (file_exists('./theimage.jpg')) {
  echo 'File exists';
} else {
  echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

Which if I apply to your code would be:

```
<div class="wrapper"><a href="store.php?url=<?php echo $row->url ?>"><img src="images/stores/category/
if (empty($row->image) or !file_exists('./images/stores/category/'.$row->image)) { 
    echo 'generic.jpg';
}else{                  
    echo $row->imagen; }?>" alt="<?php echo $row->seo ?>"/></a></div>        
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this works fine! the previous answer works fine too, what's exactly the difference, i was missing the path.

Answer (score 0):

mind the typo $row->imagen.
As I see $row->image contains only the filename. Unless the picture is in your current working directory, you need the full path for file_exists:

```
file_exists('htdocs/path/to/my/images/' . $row->image)==false)
```

To learn the path you need, place a php-file into the pictures folder with the content

```
die(__FILE__);
```

Best regards

Comment: thanks for your answers! all solutions works, i was missing the path, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

we have almost same problem. but for me; How could not display the crock image/ empty image from my Database using 
`<?php if(!empty($row[image])){ ?>";
<img class='img-size' src='admin/upload_images/".$row['image']."'>
<?php } ?>` 
it won't work.

Comment: @Ph.T can you help me out?